# How to solve "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application finished with failed status"?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
cancerdetector@cluster-cancerdetector-m:~/SparkBWA/build$ spark-submit --class SparkBWA --master yarn-cluster --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs:///user/spark/spark-assembly.jar --driver-memory 1500m --executor-memory 1500m --executor-cores 1 --archives ./bwa.zip --verbose ./SparkBWA.jar -algorithm mem -reads paired -index /Data/HumanBase/hg38 -partitions 32 ERR000589_1.filt.fastq ERR000589_2.filt.fastqhb Output_ERR000589
    Using properties file: /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    Adding default property: spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    Adding default property: spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    Adding default property: spark.eventLog.enabled=true
    Adding default property: spark.driver.maxResultSize=1920m
    Adding default property: spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
    Adding default property: spark.yarn.historyServer.address=cluster-cancerdetector-m:18080
    Adding default property: spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata=false
    Adding default property: spark.driver.memory=3840m
    Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=10000
    Adding default property: spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio=0.0
    Adding default property: spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=558
    Adding default property: spark.yarn.am.memory=5586m
    Adding default property: spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    Adding default property: spark.master=yarn-client
    Adding default property: spark.executor.memory=5586m
    Adding default property: spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
    Adding default property: spark.executor.cores=2
    Adding default property: spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=558
    Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1
    Adding default property: spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=10000
    Adding default property: spark.akka.frameSize=512
    Parsed arguments:
    master yarn-cluster
    deployMode cluster
    executorMemory 1500m
    executorCores 1
    totalExecutorCores null
    propertiesFile /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
    driverMemory 1500m
    driverCores null
    driverExtraClassPath null
    driverExtraLibraryPath null
    driverExtraJavaOptions -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    supervise false
    queue null
    numExecutors null
    files null
    pyFiles null
    archives file:/home/cancerdetector/SparkBWA/build/./bwa.zip
    mainClass SparkBWA
    primaryResource file:/home/cancerdetector/SparkBWA/build/./SparkBWA.jar
    name SparkBWA
    childArgs [-algorithm mem -reads paired -index /Data/HumanBase/hg38 -partitions 32 ERR000589_1.filt.fastq ERR000589_2.filt.fastqhb Output_ERR000589]
    jars null
    packages null
    packagesExclusions null
    repositories null
    verbose true
    Spark properties used, including those specified through
    --conf and those from the properties file /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
    spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead -> 558
    spark.driver.memory -> 1500m
    spark.yarn.jar -> hdfs:///user/spark/spark-assembly.jar
    spark.executor.memory -> 5586m
    spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> cluster-cancerdetector-m:18080
    spark.eventLog.enabled -> true
    spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio -> 0.0
    spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors -> 10000
    spark.akka.frameSize -> 512
    spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share /google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata -> false
    spark.shuffle.service.enabled -> true
    spark.history.fs.logDirectory -> hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors -> 10000
    spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors -> 1
    spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 558
    spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    spark.eventLog.dir -> hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    spark.yarn.am.memory -> 5586m
    spark.driver.maxResultSize -> 1920m
    spark.master -> yarn-client
    spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled -> true
    spark.executor.cores -> 2
    Main class: org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client
    Arguments:
    --name SparkBWA
    --driver-memory 1500m
    --executor-memory 1500m
    --executor-cores 1
    --archives file:/home/cancerdetector/SparkBWA/build/./bwa.zip
    --jar file:/home/cancerdetector/SparkBWA/build/./SparkBWA.jar
    --class SparkBWA
    -algorithm mem
    -reads paired
    -index /Data/HumanBase/hg38
    -partitions 32
    ERR000589_1.filt.fastq
    ERR000589_2.filt.fastqhb
    Output_ERR000589
    System properties:
    spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead -> 558
    spark.driver.memory -> 1500m
    spark.yarn.jar -> hdfs:///user/spark/spark-assembly.jar
    spark.executor.memory -> 1500m
    spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> cluster-cancerdetector-m:18080
    spark.eventLog.enabled -> true
    spark.scheduler.minRegisteredResourcesRatio -> 0.0
    SPARK_SUBMIT -> true
    spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors -> 10000
    spark.akka.frameSize -> 512
    spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata -> false
    spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -> -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    spark.app.name -> SparkBWA
    spark.shuffle.service.enabled -> true
    spark.history.fs.logDirectory -> hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors -> 10000
    spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors -> 1
    spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 558
    spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -> -Xbootclasspath/p:/usr/local/share/google/alpn/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
    spark.submit.deployMode -> cluster
    spark.eventLog.dir -> hdfs://cluster-cancerdetector-m/user/spark/eventlog
    spark.yarn.am.memory -> 5586m
    spark.driver.maxResultSize -> 1920m
    spark.master -> yarn-cluster
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled -> true
spark.executor.cores -> 1
Classpath elements:
spark.yarn.am.memory is set but does not apply in cluster mode.
spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead is set but does not apply in cluster mode.
16/07/31 01:12:39 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at cluster-cancerdetector-m/10.132.0.2:8032 16/07/31 01:12:40 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1467990031555_0106
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1467990031555_0106 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    atorg.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:7  31)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

When I tried to  check the AM and executor logs. the command didn't work, So I tried to manually access into NM's log dir to see the detailed application logs. Here are the application logs from the NM's log file:

```
2016-07-31 01:12:40,387 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073742335_1511{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,387 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073742335_1511{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,391 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/cancerdetector/.sparkStaging/application_1467990031555_0106/SparkBWA.jar is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-762268348_1
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,419 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742336_1512{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} for /user/cancerdetector/.sparkStaging/application_1467990031555_0106/bwa.zip
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,445 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073742336_1512{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,446 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073742336_1512{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,448 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/cancerdetector/.sparkStaging/application_1467990031555_0106/bwa.zip is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-762268348_1
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,495 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742337_1513{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} for /user/cancerdetector/.sparkStaging/application_1467990031555_0106/__spark_conf__2552000168715758347.zip
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,506 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073742337_1513{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,506 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073742337_1513{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 0
    2016-07-31 01:12:40,509 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/cancerdetector/.sparkStaging/application_1467990031555_0106/__spark_conf__2552000168715758347.zip is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-762268348_1
    2016-07-31 01:12:44,720 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742338_1514{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} for /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_1.inprogress
    2016-07-31 01:12:44,877 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* fsync: /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_1.inprogress for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1111833453_14
    2016-07-31 01:12:45,373 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073742338_1514{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 231
    2016-07-31 01:12:45,375 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073742338_1514{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 231
    2016-07-31 01:12:45,379 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_1.inprogress is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1111833453_14
    2016-07-31 01:12:45,843 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.b7989393-f278-477c-8e83-ff5da9079e8a is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:12:49,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073742339_1515{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} for /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_2.inprogress
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,100 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* fsync: /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_2.inprogress for DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_378341726_14
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,737 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.4:50010 is added to blk_1073742339_1515{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 231
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,738 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 10.132.0.3:50010 is added to blk_1073742339_1515{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-19f52f20-0053-443d-bf33-dd636d8b2d07:NORMAL:10.132.0.3:50010|RBW], ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-6b7272d9-24d2-4d77-85e2-49c492bd12a4:NORMAL:10.132.0.4:50010|RBW]]} size 231
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/application_1467990031555_0106_2.inprogress is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_378341726_14
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,892 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addToInvalidates: blk_1073742335_1511 10.132.0.3:50010 10.132.0.4:50010 
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,892 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addToInvalidates: blk_1073742337_1513 10.132.0.3:50010 10.132.0.4:50010 
    2016-07-31 01:12:50,892 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addToInvalidates: blk_1073742336_1512 10.132.0.3:50010 10.132.0.4:50010 
    2016-07-31 01:12:51,804 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* BlockManager: ask 10.132.0.3:50010 to delete [blk_1073742336_1512, blk_1073742337_1513, blk_1073742335_1511]
    2016-07-31 01:12:54,804 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* BlockManager: ask 10.132.0.4:50010 to delete [blk_1073742336_1512, blk_1073742337_1513, blk_1073742335_1511]
    2016-07-31 01:12:55,868 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.46380a1f-b5fd-4924-96aa-f59dcae0cbec is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:05,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 244 Total time for transactions(ms): 5 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 234 SyncTimes(ms): 221 
    2016-07-31 01:13:05,885 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.7273ee28-eb1c-4fe2-98d2-c5a20ebe4ffa is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:15,892 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.0f640743-d06c-4583-ac95-9d520dc8f301 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:25,902 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.bc63864c-0267-47b5-bcc1-96ba81d6c9a5 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:35,910 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.93557793-2ba2-47e8-b54c-234c861b6e6c is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:45,918 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.0fdf083c-3c53-4051-af16-d579f700962e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:13:55,927 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.834632f1-d9c6-4e14-9354-72f8c18f66d0 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:05,933 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 262 Total time for transactions(ms): 5 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 252 SyncTimes(ms): 236 
    2016-07-31 01:14:05,936 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.d06ef3b4-873f-464d-9cd0-e360da48e194 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:15,944 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.32ccba74-5f6c-45fc-b5db-26efb1b840e2 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:25,952 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.fef919cd-9952-4af8-a49a-e6dd2aa032f1 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:35,961 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.77ffdf36-8e42-43d8-9c1f-df6f3d11700d is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:45,968 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.c31cfcbb-b47c-4169-ab0f-7ae87d4f815d is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:14:55,976 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.6429570d-fb0a-4117-bb12-127a67e0a0b7 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:05,981 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 280 Total time for transactions(ms): 6 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 270 SyncTimes(ms): 253 
    2016-07-31 01:15:05,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.8030b18d-05f2-4520-b5c4-2fe42338b92b is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:15,991 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.f608a0f4-e730-43cd-a19d-da57caac346e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:25,999 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.9d5a1f80-2f2a-43a7-84f1-b26a8c90a98f is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:36,007 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.279e96fc-180c-47a5-a3ba-cfda581eedad is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:46,015 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.a85bbf52-61f4-4899-98b1-23615a549774 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:15:56,023 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.80613e8e-7015-4aeb-81df-49884bd0eb5e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:06,028 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 298 Total time for transactions(ms): 6 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 288 SyncTimes(ms): 267 
    2016-07-31 01:16:06,031 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.2be7fc48-bd1c-4042-88e4-239b1c630458 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:16,038 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.40fc68a6-f003-4e35-b4b3-50bd3c4a0c82 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:26,045 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.97e7d15c-4d28-4089-b4a5-9f0935a72589 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:36,052 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.84d8e78d-90fd-419f-9000-fa04ab56955e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:46,059 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.6691cc3e-6969-4a8f-938f-272d1c96701d is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:16:56,066 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.077143b6-281a-468c-8b2c-bcb6cd3bc27a is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:06,070 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 316 Total time for transactions(ms): 6 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 306 SyncTimes(ms): 284 
    2016-07-31 01:17:06,073 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.817d1886-aea2-450a-a586-08677dc18d60 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:16,080 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.abd46886-1359-4c5e-8276-ea4f2969411f is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:26,087 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.24625260-59be-4a9b-b47b-b8d5b76cb789 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:36,096 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.11630782-e50e-4260-a0da-99845bc3f1db is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:46,103 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.16cdd027-f1b8-4cbf-a30c-2f1712f4abb5 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:17:56,111 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.93fb2e86-2fec-4069-b73b-632750fda603 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:06,116 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 334 Total time for transactions(ms): 6 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 324 SyncTimes(ms): 300 
    2016-07-31 01:18:06,119 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.b19fddda-ea90-49ab-b44d-434cce28cb67 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:16,127 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.d81ab189-bde5-4878-b82b-903983466f86 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:26,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.e5b51632-f714-4814-b896-59bba137b42d is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:36,144 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.39791121-9399-4a22-a50c-90eaddf31ffb is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:46,153 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.861c269b-5466-4855-84fd-587ed3306012 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:18:56,162 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.8a9ff721-bd56-4bea-b399-31bfaabe8c7c is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:06,168 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 352 Total time for transactions(ms): 7 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 342 SyncTimes(ms): 313 
    2016-07-31 01:19:06,170 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.492bf987-4991-4533-80e2-678efa843cb9 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:16,178 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.9294c0c6-43db-4f6d-9d31-f493143b6baf is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:26,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.341dd131-c14c-4147-bcbc-849d1d6bba8c is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:36,196 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.56f92e8e-ef93-4279-a57f-472dd5d8f399 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:46,204 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.5ddcda82-b501-4043-bb54-a29902d9d234 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:19:56,212 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.31e7517b-2ef3-458c-9979-324d7a96302f is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:06,218 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 370 Total time for transactions(ms): 7 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 360 SyncTimes(ms): 329 
    2016-07-31 01:20:06,220 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.5251f5df-0957-4008-b664-8d82eaa9789e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:16,229 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.3320b948-2478-4807-9ab3-d23e4945765e is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:26,237 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.0928c940-e57d-4a34-a7dc-53dade7ff909 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:36,246 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.6240fcdf-696e-49c4-a883-3eda5ab89b4d is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:46,254 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.5622850e-b7b0-458a-9ffa-89e134fa3fda is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
    2016-07-31 01:20:56,262 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/spark/eventlog/.faa076e8-490c-489f-8183-778325e0b144 is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1615501432_1
```

Comment: Can you access the Spark history server logs? I don't think the NodeManager is where you should look for Spark job status

Comment: When I try to access logs by this command
yarn logs -applicationId application_1467990031555_0106
the comand doesn't work although I have set yarn.log-aggregation-enable to true

Comment: Again, yarn isn't the Spark history server.

Comment: The application log files links are in the next comment

Comment: https://egyptscholars-my.sharepoint.com/personal/asmaa_ali_egyptscholars_org/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=ekFCoViQdVNUJMKIKwo4PO%2fxO709iGYdrJJCZB2P%2b8w%3d&docid=0056133ddcb4b4895bd9afd8425a4257a&rev=1

https://egyptscholars-my.sharepoint.com/personal/asmaa_ali_egyptscholars_org/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=LngF1SuYA5XzorL4be4RI2gElEfZqnmEmOfzedYs7k4%3d&docid=053d58708407743448821f5229024f792&rev=1

Comment: One problem with `yarn logs -applicationId` can occur, if your user is not allowed to read the logs (which can be root too!)

Answer (score 8):

First, you need to find out what host/node was chosen as the host for ApplicationMaster. Go to the YARN UI and look for the Spark application.

When you have the node, go to the logs on the disk like `logs/userlogs/application_1469891809555_0005/container_1469891809555_0005_01_000001/stderr`. You need to find `stderr` for container `000001` which is the container for `ApplicationMaster` for the Spark application.